# how to press enter to exit python program using a while loop

Tags: python

program keeps on looping when pressing enter.

The program print goodbye on preesin enter, but then keeps on looping back again

How can I exit, when pressing enter(without using break)?

```
choice = input("Enter selection:,\n "
               "(X) exit,\n "
               "(1) Celsius to kelvin,\n "
               "(2) celsius to fahrenheit,\n "
               "(3) kelvin to celsius,\n "
               "(4) kelvin to fahrenheit,\n "
               "(5) fahrenhiet to celsius,\n "
               "(6) fahrenheit to kelvin\n")
choice = choice.upper()

while choice[0] != "X" :     
    if choice[0] == '1':
        celsius = input("Enter Celsius(integer), or press enter to exit")
        while celsius:
            celsius = int(celsius)
            #function to convert Celsius to kelvin
            answer = cel_to_kel(celsius)
            print("Kelvin is ", answer)
            celsius = input("Enter celsius, or press enter to exit")
        print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: That should work... what is the error?

Comment: When the program loops after printing `Goodbye` then there must be some outer loop that's not included in the code posted. Also the indentation is not correct.

Comment: Yes it is not the full code, I will post the full code, I thought the isuues was with this piece of code

Comment: Thank you. Now it looks good. Let's wait and see if anyone can say how to fix the problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try using:

```
while 1:
  celsius = input("Enter celsius, or press enter to exit")
  if not celsius:
    break
  #function to convert Celsius to kelvin
  answer = cel_to_kel(int(celsius))
  print("Kelvin is ", answer)

print("Goodbye")
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an if statement that looks at the value:

```
if celsius == "":
    break
```

Pressing enter returns an empty string with input, so using an if statement you can check to see if it is empty or not. After that, it's as simple as breaking the loop (or doing something else you want).

Comment: in fact I aleady have this piece of code above 

while choice[0] != "X" :     
    if choice[0] == '1':

where X is for exiting the application

Comment: If you want to completely exit the code rather than just the loop, import sys then replace `break` with `sys.exit()`

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The problem is that you have two loops with different conditions:

```
choice = input()
while choice != "X":
    if choice == "1":
        celsius = input()
        while celsius:
            ...
            celsius = input()
```

The inner loop stops once the user doesn't input anything to `celsius`. But the outer loop keeps running forever because `choice` never changes.

## Solution "Only one choice"

If you want the program to exit once the inner loop finishes then you can remove the outer loop completely:

```
choice = input()
if choice == "1":
    celsius = input()
    while celsius:
        ...
        celsius = input()
```

## Solution "Switch between choices"

If you want to give the user the option to switch to a different conversion type then add another `input` at the end of the main loop:

```
choice = input()
while choice != "X":
    if choice == "1":
        celsius = input()
        while celsius:
            ...
            celsius = input()
    choice = input()
```

## Solution "Choices without loop"

If you want the user to select the type for each conversion independently then remove the inner loop:

```
choice = input()
while choice != "X":
    if choice == "1":
        celsius = input()
        if celsius:
            ...            
    choice = input()
```